# Why don't I get good hits when searching "Poor man's" with quotes?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, search

If I wanted to search about the phrase "Poor man's X",

The question [When did the expression "Poor man's <noun>" originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110676/when-did-the-expression-poor-mans-noun-originate) appears when I [search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Poor%20man%27s) for

> Poor man's

But if I use [quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Poor%20man%27s%22)

> "Poor man's"

I get three hits, but not the optimal hit.

Removing the apostrophe and the "s" [doesn't help](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Poor%20man%22)

> "Poor man"

I get six hits, but not the optimal hit.

Why do I get sub-optimal search results when using quotes? Is this related to the apostrophe?

Comment: The apostrophe does seem to make a difference. Try ["poor man’s"](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22poor+man’s%22) with a curly apostrophe. Different again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you don't get good results using the Stack Exchange internal search facility is because a single general-purpose search engine is common to all SE sites. Some of the things it does (ignoring short words and punctuation marks, etc.) are a net benefit on most other sites, but not on ELU.

So I don't usually bother with them. Google's "site-specific" search facility works fine...

> site:http://english.stackexchange.com "Poor man's"
>    ...which returns [***these 98 results as required***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com%20%22Poor%20man%27s%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com%20%22Poor%20man%27s%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3884846j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The same idea has been mentioned in previous meta answers by various people.  For example, in [my answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3100/11433) to meta question [How would we like to format our keywords?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3091), I suggested using a google search string that includes text `site:english.stackexchange.com/questions -newest -recently` .  The latter search terms reduce hits on non-question pages.